# ternary operator inside a component tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

Is it possible to use ternary operator within a built-in component tag? For instance, I am using Touchable Opacity from React Native (Native Base):

```
type ItemProps = {
  title: string;
  face: string;
};

export const Item: React.FunctionComponent<ItemProps> = ({
  title,
  face,
}) => {

  const [showAddFriendPage, setShowAddFriendPage] = useState(false);

  const toggleAddFriendPage = () => {
    setShowAddFriendPage(showAddFriendPage ? false : true);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8}
    onPress={() =>
      setShowAddFriendPage(true)
    }   >
      <View>
        <Thumbnail small source={{ uri: face }} style={styles.thumbnail} />
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={styles.title}>
          {title}
        </Text>
        <AddFriendPage
          showAddFriendPage={showAddFriendPage}
          toggleShowPage={toggleAddFriendPage}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

Currently the onPress navigation is applied to all Items regardless of what title or face was used. I want to introduce a conditional navigation. For instance, if the

`title == 'news'`

then `onPress...`. Since we can't use if else statements within jsx, I was trying ternary operators:

```
 <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8}
 {title == 'news'? {
      onPress={() =>
      setShowAddFriendPage(true)
    }   
    } }
/>
```

But this clearly doesn't work. I get `'...' expected.`on `title`.

`No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'onPress'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)`on `onPress`and

```
Cannot find name 'setShowAddFriendPage'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
         <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8}
              onPress={() =>{
               if(title == 'news'){
                setShowAddFriendPage(true)
                }
          }}   
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to create an `onPress` function that has different behavior based on your condition.

```js
const onPress = useCallback(() => {
  if (title === 'news') {
    setShowAddFriendPage(true)
  }
}, [title])
```

It has a dependency on `title`, so it will be re-created, and the component re-rendered only if `title` changes.

Then use it as such:

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={onPress}>
  {/* … */}
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use spread operator (...) to conditionally add props to components.

```
<TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.8}
    {...(title == 'news' && { onPress: () => setShowAddFriendPage(true) })}
/>
```

This way component will have `onPress` prop whenever title equals to `'news'`

Comment: @BertrandMarron Do you mean it's not clean?